# Looping through two lists one element at a time

Tags: python

I have two identical lists. I want to take the first element from list 1 and compare it each element in list 2 and once finished I want to take the second element from list 1 and repeat until the each element has been compared to each other from both lists.

I have created a Levenshtein Distance model and have been able to successfully loop 1 string (that I hard code) through my second list. However I will need to make this more practical and have the target string as a list and have it switch to the next element once it has finished comparing the previous element to the second list. Then I only want it to return values greater than a specific threshold ex. 80.00

```
my_list = address['Street'].tolist()
my_list

# Import numpy to perform the matrix algebra necessary to calculate the fuzzy match
import numpy as np
# Define a function that will become the fuzzy match
# I decided to use Levenshtein Distance due to the formulas ability to handle string comparisons of two unique lengths
def string_match(seq1, seq2, ratio_calc = False):
    """ levenshtein_ratio_and_distance:
        Calculates levenshtein distance between two strings.
        If ratio_calc = True, the function computes the
        levenshtein distance ratio of similarity between two strings
        For all i and j, distance[i,j] will contain the Levenshtein
        distance between the first i characters of seq1 and the
        first j characters of seq2
    """
    # Initialize matrix of zeros
    rows = len(seq1)+1
    cols = len(seq2)+1
    distance = np.zeros((rows,cols),dtype = int)

    # Populate matrix of zeros with the indeces of each character of both strings
    for i in range(1, rows):
        for k in range(1,cols):
            distance[i][0] = i
            distance[0][k] = k

    # loop through the matrix to compute the cost of deletions,insertions and/or substitutions    
    for col in range(1, cols):
        for row in range(1, rows):
            if seq1[row-1] == seq2[col-1]:
                cost = 0 # If the characters are the same in the two strings in a given position [i,j] then the cost is 0
            else:
                # In order to align the results with those of the Python Levenshtein package, if we choose to calculate the ratio
                # the cost of a substitution is 2. If we calculate just distance, then the cost of a substitution is 1.
                if ratio_calc == True:
                    cost = 2
                else:
                    cost = 1
            distance[row][col] = min(distance[row-1][col] + 1,      # Cost of deletions
                                 distance[row][col-1] + 1,          # Cost of insertions
                                 distance[row-1][col-1] + cost)     # Cost of substitutions
    if ratio_calc == True:
        # Computation of the Levenshtein Distance Ratio
        Ratio = round(((len(seq1)+len(seq2)) - distance[row][col]) / (len(seq1)+len(seq2)) * 100, 2)
        return Ratio
    else:
        # print(distance) # Uncomment if you want to see the matrix showing how the algorithm computes the cost of deletions,
        # insertions and/or substitutions
        # This is the minimum number of edits needed to convert seq1 to seq2
        return distance[row][col]


Prev_addrs = my_list

target_addr = "830 Amsterdam ave"
for addr in Prev_addrs:
    distance = string_match(target_addr, addr, ratio_calc = True)
    print(distance)
```

Comment: So the specific problem you have is in how to construct the loops and then how to save the output if LD>80? Where are you getting a problem?

Comment: Regarding the loops, are you looking for something like [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)?

Comment: The comparing all combinations of list1 and list2 sounds like a job for [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: @bart cubrich that is exactly right. I am not sure how to construct the loop and still get it to fit into my function

Comment: I will look into the itertools .product. that look like a solid way to start solving my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring what I consider all the irrelevant code in your question, here's how to accomplish what I think is the essence of your question from its title and first paragraph.

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

def compare(a, b):
    print('compare({}, {}) called'.format(a, b))

list1 = list('ABCD')
list2 = list('EFGH')

for a, b in itertools.product(list1, list2):
    compare(a, b)
```

Output:

```
compare(A, E) called
compare(A, F) called
compare(A, G) called
compare(A, H) called
compare(B, E) called
compare(B, F) called
compare(B, G) called
compare(B, H) called
compare(C, E) called
compare(C, F) called
compare(C, G) called
compare(C, H) called
compare(D, E) called
compare(D, F) called
compare(D, G) called
compare(D, H) called
```

Comment: I just provided the extra code for background toward solving the problem, but yes that is the core of my question. My real problem is how do I get these iterated pairs through my function (that is why i provided my function as well). Thank you for addressing the core of my issue!

Comment: Yes. Thank you for all of your help martineau!